# Using Datagrab module with Structure and blueprints, it is throwing error on edit channel entry

Tags: channel-entries, structure, datagrab, csv

I am having a CSV file and i am using Datagrab module to importing CSV for a channel (eg: XYZ) . It works fine.

Also i am using Structure and blueprints module in my project. 
After successful CSV import, when i access the channel (named as eg: XYZ), it is showing that entries BUT when i edit a entry then i am getting following errors :

```
A PHP Error was encountered 
Severity: Notice 
Message: Undefined index: 4318 
Filename: blueprints/ext.blueprints.php 
Line Number: 174

A PHP Error was encountered 
Severity: Notice 
Message: Undefined index: 4318 
Filename: structure/tab.structure.php 
Line Number: 164
```

How can i remove the errors?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're running the latest version of Structure and EE, otherwise you'll need to test adding entires without datagrab and see if that's the issue. If they stay, please start a Structure support ticket.

Comment: yes, i am running following version:  
2.7.2 for EE and 3.3.13 for Structure.
It is throwing error after importing CSV from datagrab.

Comment: i think it is issue with datagrab while importing CSV.
so can you suggest any solution for the same ?